# How to make a parbox extend to end of the line

Tags: tex-core

I'm playing with the [paperandpencil](https://github.com/baradhili/paperandpencil-latex) library and wanting to change the answer underline to be able to extend to the end of the line it is in.
I've pulled the command out for the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\linetext}[1]{\raisebox{-4.5mm}{\parbox{6.5cm}{\hrule\strut \centering\footnotesize {\em #1}}}}

\begin{document}

    This is something \linetext{stuff below the line} 

\end{document}
```

Output - 
[image: Output from mwe]

As you can see it puts a fixed 6.5cm line in... ideally I'd like that to be able to optionally run to the end of the line it is in - but I'm at a loss as how to do it.. I naively thought changing the \hrule to \hrulefill would do the job, but no..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `\linegoal` dimension provided by the package of the same name:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\newcommand{\linetext}[1]{\raisebox{-4.5mm}{\parbox{\linegoal}{\hrule\strut \centering\footnotesize {\em #1}}}}

\begin{document}

    This is something \linetext{stuff below the line}

\end{document}
```